# Is there any way to catch errors that come in HTTP reponse for example status code 500, and then fail the script in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a simple script and I want selenium to fail the script or at least log the errors that come in http response.

Answer (score 0):

Stable Selenium versions (below 4) are not supporting such functionality.
It has no ability to read HTTP responses.
Tools like Rest Assured are used for such things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *browsermob-proxy* tool to achieve that. You only should understand that when you call a page is actually causes a lot of requests to (different) servers and each responds with its own code.

For example the code could look like:

```java
@BeforeTest
public void setUp(){
    /*
    Create and start proxy instance here
    Configure driver to use that created proxy here
     */
}

@Test
public void testHeaders(){
    // Create a map that would be storing url-to-status association
    // Use synchronized version of a hash map because
    // proxy handles connections in parallel
    Map<String, Integer> urlToStatuses = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    // Configure handler that would be listening for responses
    // and fill the map
    browserMobProxy.addResponseFilter((response, contents, messageInfo) -> {
        urlToStatuses.put(messageInfo.getOriginalUrl(), response.status().code());
    });
    
    // Call a page
    driver.get("https://google.com");
    
    // Test the code of required URL
    Assert.assertEquals(urlToStatuses.get("https://google.com").intValue(), 200);
    
    // Do no forget to clear the map before the next assertion
    urlToStatuses.clear();        
}
```